# How to get request.environ values in python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-2.7, django-views

When using

```
request.environ['QUERY_STRING']
```

I am getting value `ugq_no=2`, but how can I get value as **2** ?

Reference Code :

```
def get_ugall_record(request):           
    qry_obj = db.Query(user_guide).order('ugq_no')             
    all_list = []    
    for q in qry_obj: 
        all_list.append(q)  
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', all_list), mimetype='application/json')

def get_faqall_record(request):        
    qry_obj = db.Query(faqs).order('faq_no')             
    all_list = []    
    for q in qry_obj: 
        all_list.append(q)  
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', all_list), mimetype='application/json')
```

I want to make these two functions in one function.

So I am trying with :

```
def get_ugall_record(request): 
    logging.debug('----1-----')
    logging.debug(request.GET.get('ugq_no'))
    if request.GET.get('ugq_no') != 'None':
        logging.debug('----2-----')
        ug_qry_obj = db.Query(user_guide).order('ugq_no')             
        ug_all_list = []    
        for q in ug_qry_obj: 
            ug_all_list.append(q)  
        return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', ug_all_list), mimetype='application/json')
    elif request.GET.get('faq_no') != 'None':  
        logging.debug('----3-----')
        qry_obj = db.Query(faqs).order('faq_no')             
        all_list = []    
        for q in qry_obj: 
            all_list.append(q)  
        return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', all_list), mimetype='application/json')
```

But this is not going in elif request.GET.get('faq_no') != 'None'
What can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`urlparse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> formdata = urlparse.parse_qs('ugq_no=2')
>>> formdata
{'ugq_no': ['2']}
>>> formdata['ugq_no']
['2']
>>> formdata['ugq_no'][0]
'2'
```

In Python 3.x, Use [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> formdata = urllib.parse.parse_qs('ugq_no=2')
>>> formdata
{'ugq_no': ['2']}
>>> formdata['ugq_no']
['2']
>>> formdata['ugq_no'][0]
'2'
```

---

Or using [`request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET):

```
value = request.GET.get('ugq_no')
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
def get_ugall_record(request): 
    if 'ugq_no' in request.GET:
        qry_obj = db.Query(user_guide).order('ugq_no')             
        return qry_response(qry_obj)
    elif 'faq_no' in request.GET:
        qry_obj = db.Query(faqs).order('faq_no')             
        return qry_response(qry_obj)

def qry_response(qry_obj):
    all_list = []
    for q in qry_obj:
        all_list.append(q)
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', all_list), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: I want to combine two python functions whose functionality is same but for two js function two urls and two python functions respectively are written. I want to combine those python functions into one with one url. in this example ugq_no is one key and other is suppose ugq_no2. How Can I add if and elif for these two keys

Comment: @eegloo, Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @eegloo, I read the edited question. I still don't understand what you mean. BTW, why do you define `get_faqall_record` twice?

Comment: oh I am sorry. I got the answer just now. Thanks for help.

Comment: @eegloo, I read your edited question. I still don't understand what you want.

Comment: @eegloo, Do you pass `ugq_no`, `faq_no` at the same time in javascript ?

Comment: @eegloo, I added an updated code. Check it out. If It is not what you want, please clarify your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41925/discussion-between-eegloo-and-falsetru)